# Slack Oauth/Authorize API Call

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, authorization, slack-api

I'm new to OAuth (and the Slack API) and have a question regarding Step 1 of Slack's [OAuth Flow](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth).

It says "Your web or mobile app should redirect users to the following url: https://slack.com/oauth/authorize".  At first I thought I should do an XHR request but then came to understand that that is not what I want.

After more research, I found that the initial oauth/authorize request should be sent as a direct request in the browser.  My problem is I can't begin to visualize how this should be done.  I've been referencing parts of this [tutorial](https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified) (scroll down to 'Web Server Apps' section) but it doesn't help me to be able to wrap my head around the oauth/authorize petition.

So basically, I'm looking for someone to better explain to me how that initial petition is supposed to be made.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you building a web app? Just give the user a hyperlink to click on to go to `/authorize` or return a redirect (302). In a mobile app, you'd want to open the default browser or perhaps an embedded web view.

Comment: At the moment it is just a script (js) file.  I am not building a web app.  Can I achieve this without building a web app and just sticking to the basic script file?

Comment: I don't believe so. Slack's OAuth flow only supports redirecting to a URL, so to do OAuth you'll need a web server that can receive the redirect.

Comment: @smarx thanks for the guidance, I really appreciate it.  This helps tremendously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the [Slack button](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button) docs.

There you will find an example for your slackapp, something like:

```
<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=incoming-webhook&client_id=CLIENT_ID">
   <img alt="Add to Slack" height="40" width="139" 
   src="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png" />
</a>
```

This button asks for authorization for a slackapp that includes incoming webhooks, you can add more features needed inside scope separating them by commas. `scope=incoming-webhook,commands,bot,channels:read`

As of your tutorial link, when it says you should link them to `https://oauth2server.com/auth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=photos`

It is refering to wrap that into a button for the user:

```
<a href="https://oauth2server.com/auth?response_type=code&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&scope=photos">
   Auth Button
</a>
```

Hope this helps clarify the usage of `/oauth/authorize`